# How to handle highly Imabalanced classification?

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, machine-learning-model, boosting

I have been dealing with a classification problem. Real issue is the imbalance here

I have ~500,000 -ve samples and ~300 +ve samples.End result is predicted probabilities NOT hard 0-1 classification  Personally I am not a big fan of oversampling/under-sampling since they mess the distribution up. I also tried stratified sampling so that same proportion is kept while training but its not working. For my present approach I take a sample of -ve points (say 100,000) and then train with 300 +ve samples and getting an ROC-AUC of ~85 but almost no case predicted reaches probability >51% (after using model.predict_proba). Any tips on handling such an extreme imbalance? additionally I would only like to stay with tree based or boosting models since they provide interpretability (hence avoiding neural network, anomaly detection , autoencoder for now).
Any hints, resources appreciated!
Below is the code I am using.

```
df = read_data(path)
Pkl_Filename = path + "/catboost.pkl"
# if not os.path.exists(Pkl_Filename):
X = df.drop(ep_config['target_field'], axis=1)
y = df[ep_config['target_field']]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, stratify=y)
clf = CatBoostClassifier(eval_metric='Recall', use_best_model=True, scale_pos_weight=...)
sm = SMOTE(random_state=27, ratio=1.0)
X_train, y_train = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)
smote = clf.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=(X_test, y_test))

# smote_pred = smote.predict(X_test)

# Checking accuracy
# accuracy_score(y_test, smote_pred)
# clf.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=(X_test, y_test))
with open(Pkl_Filename, 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(smote, file)
# else:
#     clf = pickle.loads(Pkl_Filename)
logging.info('the test roc is :{:.6f}'.format(roc_auc_score(y_test, smote.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])))
```

Answer (score 1):

have you already tried using only very little of the -ve cases? So for example to train your model on 900 points total, 600/300? Then stratified sampling should still work fine. Then I'd evaluate your model based on it's ability to predict -ve cases and just monitor the performance it get's on the (in your case) gigantic test dataset that the model hasn't seen before.

Also, you could generate "synthetic" +ve cases by bootstrapping from the real data to see how that influences the model. Similar to what is described here: https://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/specific/articulo/dupret_science.pdf

Comment: as I said , we are using training on very little -ve cases for example 10,000 -ve and 300 +ve (along with class weights of course) . so this thing is not working good. by not good i mean ~65 roc auc and no positive predicted class has probability >51%. by generating synthetic samples you mean oversampling/undersampling/smote right ?

Comment: I think I'd go a lot lower with your sample number first. You can always add more data later since you already have it. Let's say you're doing stratified k-fold with k=10. That'd roughly give you 27 +ve in your training set which is probably not enough for the model to actually "learn it" in the imho. So maybe randomly pick -ve a couple times and try with very little data first. Decision trees should still perform reasonably well.

Yeah, SMOTE would be sth you could try

Comment: so you are saying to pick around 1000 -ve and +ve and then train ?(using stratified sampling of course) and after that smote?

Comment: I would try two approaches: First, pick around 1000 -ve and your 300 +ve, train a cross-validated model and then see how it performs. If it's not garbage, see how it performs on the remaining -ve data points. You could even try a k-fold approach in which every new -ve set is truly new and randomly sampled from the whole data. The other approach would be to use SMOTE to generate synthetic +ve cases based on the existing one and then see how a model on that performs. But for this I also wouldn't take ALL of your -ve cases.

Comment: "But for this I also wouldn't take ALL of your -ve cases"
why? oh ok.so essentially split the data first into train and test and do oversampling only on train and leave test untouched right

Comment: Due to the massive class imbalance, I would personally not impute too many synthetic cases since this could lead to overfitting. And then I would just benchmark how your model's performance on both the used data and the left-out data changes if you add more and more true -ve cases.

Comment: ok so finally the solution is either smote or careful cross validation right?
and as given in post i am using catboost model , i think that should be ok or should i try lightgbm, random forest too?